# Using Dart in Chrome extension content script does not run?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart

I am trying to write a Chrome extension using Dart. So far everything goes well except for the content script --- the "main" function in the content script dart file does not seem to run.

To be more specific, first of all Dartium cannot be used since giving a dart file in the "js" rule in the manifest caused Dartium to complain; I next tried to compile the dart file (with csp: true) then make the manifest to include the compiled js file directly --- then I'm stuck, it seems that no matter what I try, the (compiled) "main" function just does not run.

Any suggestions?

Update:

The manifest file:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Assistant",
  "description": "Assists you with various tasks.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "26.0",
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "storage"],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "packages/browser/dart.js",
        "dart_content_script.dart.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "bulb.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  }
}
```

The content script dart file:

```
void main() {
  print('main done');
}
```

The pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
name: AssistentExtension

dependencies:
  browser: any
  chrome: any

dev_dependencies:
  unittest: '>=0.10.0'

transformers:
- $dart2js:
    csp: true
```

In the Chrome developer console, I can find the string "main done" meaning that the "main" function is indeed included in the compiled js, but nothing is printed meaning it is not run.

Comment: Showing some code and the manifest would be appropriate.

Comment: How do you run it? Conext menu on `manifest.json` > Run as Chrome app?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer: I loaded the extension as an unpacked extension from the Chrome extension management page.

Comment: I haven't done much with Chrome extensions and it's a while back. I just have a background page which refers the script containing main `    <script type="application/dart" src="background.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>`. This worked for me.
`

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Thanks for the info. Yeah, in situation where I have a html, Dart just works --- the pain here is for the content script, where is no support html...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689187

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like yours. At that time I looked into the **console logs**, a log saying chrome package is missing (but i don't know what cause it), so I manually added it back to build folder, then it worked so I can see my logs written in main().

When I run **[test_ext](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/tree/master/app/test_ext)** that come with **[official chrome pub](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart)**, I get a different error message in console log, again I solved it and then the **test_ext** sample is running well too.

So, my advise is take a look at the console log, it might help. You can open **console** for extension by right click on **popup UI of extension** and select '**Inspect Element**' to open it.